# Ecto ILIKE for multiple keywords?

Tags: elixir, ecto

So right now I am using this:

```
dynamic(
  [u],
  ilike(
    u.name, ^"%#{String.replace(term, "%", "\\%")}%"
  ) 
)
```

And the term is a simple string, like `"charlie"`. How would I use this with a list of terms, like: `["charlie", "dennis", "frank"]` - Is it even possible without fragments?

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is possible to some extent with a bit of metaprogramming. Luckily enough, [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) allows your own macros in the queries, so all we need would be to build our own macro, gluing several `ILIKE`s with `or`s.

There are several pitfalls here. In the first place, we should make the compiler forget about `Kernel.or/2`, otherwise, it would be trying to do logical disjunction in place. Then, we should explicitly import `Ecto.Query.API.or/2`. And, finally, we should recursively build the resulting AST to pass to the query.

Summing up.

```rb
defmodule MultiOr do
  import Ecto.Query
  import Kernel, except: [or: 2]
  import Ecto.Query.API, only: [or: 2]

  # terminating call, we are done
  defp or_ilike(var, [term1, term2] = terms) do
    quote do
      ilike(unquote(var), unquote(term1)) or ilike(unquote(var), unquote(term2))
    end
  end

  # recursive call
  defp or_ilike(var, [term | terms]) do
    quote do
      ilike(unquote(var), unquote(term)) or unquote(or_ilike(var, terms))
    end
  end

  # the macro wrapper to inject AST
  defmacrop multi_ilike(var, terms) do
    Macro.expand(or_ilike(var, terms), __CALLER__)
  end

  # test
  def test do
    Ecto.Query.where(User, [u],
      multi_ilike(u.name, ["charlie", "dennis", "frank"]))
  end
end
```

Please note, that `or_ilike/2` are *functions*, returning AST. They cannot be macros (which might simplify everything) because one cannot recursively call macros (which should be defined upfront, before the first call.)

Let’s see.

```rb
MultiOr.test
#⇒ #Ecto.Query<from u0 in User,
#   where: ilike(u0.name, "charlie") or (ilike(u0.name, "dennis") or ilike(u0.name, "frank"))>
```

Comment: Took me several read throughs to grok this but when I finally did; thanks @Aleksei!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or_where`, from standard Ecto:

```
def multi_ilike(queryable, words) do
  for term <- words, reduce: queryable do
    acc -> 
      str = "%#{String.replace(term, "%", "\\%")}%"
      cond = dynamic([u], ilike(u.name, ^str))
      or_where(acc, ^cond)
  end
end
```

or if you don't like `for`:

```
def multi_ilike(queryable, words) do
  words
  |> Enum.map(&"%#{String.replace(&1, "%", "\\%")}%")
  |> Enum.map(&dynamic([u], ilike(u.name, ^&1))
  |> Enum.reduce(queryable, &or_where(&2, ^&1))
end
```